# yii2 query date field with other field

Tags: php, yii2

I have a table:
id,
name,
date,
warning_days

I'm trying to query the table like this:

```
$result= Table::find()->where([
'<=', 'date', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ '.'warning_days'.' days'))])->all();
```

I'm fiddling with the code, but can't seem to find a way...
Can somebody, point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance, regards, Rui

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. and also a SQL code equivalent to the active query your are trying to code

Comment: I'm trying to query dates that are lower than 'warning' days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way is the use of where method in literal format based  on date_add( )

```
 $result= Table::find()
      ->where( 'date <= date_add( date, INTERVAL warning_day  DAY)')
      ->all();
```

or you can use operator format

```
 $result= Table::find()
      ->where( ['<= ', date , 'date_add( date, INTERVAL warning_day  DAY)'])
      ->all();
```

Comment: Thank you, with a little tweek I made it work: SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `date` <= (NOW() + INTERVAL `warning_day` DAY)